# awesome-typescript-loader: spread of empty array returns empty array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, spread-syntax

Well, everything was awesome until I went into spread of the empty array to render a couple of similar index-dependable components.

I wrote this line of code (as usual):

```
[...Array(3)].map((_, i) => {...}) // return something, you know
```

or, more relatively

```
[...Array(3)].map((_, i) => i)
```

What I'm expecting and what is the normal behaviour (e.g. in Chrome's console, or what did Babel until I came to Typescript):

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

What I got in my React TypeScript application (using `webpack-dev-server` and `awesome-typescript-loader`):

```
[empty x 3]
```

I went deeper. I logged `[...Array(3)]` from my app, and then in Chrome's console. What I got:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined] // from Chrome's console
[empty x 3] // from my app
```

Obviously, this annoying thing doesn't allow me to render index-dependable components without workarounds/third-parties.
So, am I doing something wrong, or this is a bug?

Partial config:

```
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
    exclude: /node_modules/
},
{
    enforce: "pre",
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: "source-map-loader"
},
```

Versions:

```
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^4.0.0",
"typescript": "^3.0.1",
"webpack": "^3.10.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is another compiler option named `downlevelIteration`. Everything works fine when

```
"downlevelIteration": true
```

### **Additional:**

If you want to spread `HTMLCollection` or something similar (e.g. `NodeList`), you should include `dom.iterable` into `lib` option, e.g.:

```
"lib": ["es6", "dom", "dom.iterable"]
```